# retrieve previous setState and access an external variable

Tags: reactjs

I want to retrieve previous setState and have an  access to external variable when onChange input

```
  handleChangeCheckNickName(e){ console.log(e.target.value); // work fine 
         this.setState(prevState =>{
             console.log(e.target.value);
            const value = e.target.value // error
             return   {nickName: value}
             }
         )
     }

   render(){

        return(
               <form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder='Nick Name' onChange={this.handleChangeCheckNickName}/>
                <h1>{this.state.nickName}</h1>
            </form>
        )
    }
```

Then An error is occured App.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null iit's about this line

```
console.log(e.target.value);
```

Comment: Seems okay, just do console.log(e) and check if its set. How are you using `handleChangeCheckNickName`? Can you add the code of that aswell?

Comment: Thanks, i updated the question 
<form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder='Nick Name' onChange={this.handleChangeCheckNickName}/>
                <h1>{this.state.nickName}</h1>
            </form>

Answer (score 0):

```
 state = { nickName: "" };
  handleChangeCheckNickName = e => {
    this.setState({ nickName: e.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={this.state.nickName}
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChangeCheckNickName}
        />
        <h2>{this.state.nickName}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

For your reference this is how you can use previous state

```
<h3>{this.state.status?'Show ME':''}</h3>
<button onClick={this.handleShow}>Click to show</button>
```

and handleShow function

```
  handleShow=e=>{
    this.setState(prev=>({status:!prev.status}))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to retrive the previous state 
  this.setState(prevState =>{

Comment: @helmisdao for input why you need previous state value  can you explain me so that i could help you